# Post URL in php script to move webcam

Tags: php, url

when I call `.../axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?gotoserverpresetname=Eis_links1&camera=1` the attached webcam is moving to the preset position (i can change the value of `gotoserverpresetname` and it moves)...

How can I call this script from a php script?
I tried with the code below, but nothing happens..

Best regards
Adriana

```
    $myvar1="Eis_mitte";
    $myvar2="1";

    $url = '...my url....';
    $myvars = 'gotoserverpresetname='.$myvar1 . '&camera='.$myvar2;

    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

Comment: You use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, but with the needed URL you pass GET parameters. Remove CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and add variables to the $url string

Comment: I changed my code to (is that what you suggested?)  
  $url = '...thedomain.../axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?gotoserverpresetname=Eis_mitte&camera=1';

  $ch = curl_init( $url );
  $response = curl_exec( $ch );

but the cam is still not moved...

Answer (score 0):

You need a GET REQUEST:

```
$myvar1="Eis_mitte";
$myvar2="1";

$url = '...my url....';
$myvars = '?gotoserverpresetname='.$myvar1 . '&camera='.$myvar2;

$ch = curl_init( $url.$myvars );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

NOTE: Added '?' to myvars and removed CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Comment: I tried this, but it's still not moving the cam... in my url i'm adressing an cgi-script- .../axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi maybe there is a problem with this?

Comment: Are you sure you construct a valid/correct URL? If you are, maybe the problem is in PHP not able to refer to that URL - server configuration or ... I would try with other valid URL just to check that php can communicate with curl.

Comment: i tried in the terminal, there curl - i gets the 'not found' back...what does this mean for my php script?

curl -i ...my domain.../axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?gotoserverpresetname=Eis_mitte&camera=1
[1] 3253
 HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: /axis-cgi/ptz/cookietest.cgi?cgipathref=ptz
Set-Cookie: ptz_ctl_id=37798; path=/axis-cgi/;expires=Sat, 22-Feb-2014 17:34:35 GMT

Comment: I tried to add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE); this did not help